# Pushing a new List from a NavigationLink within a List freezes the simulator/canvas (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

When building a `List` View that can push a secondary `List` of items, the XCode simulator and SwiftUI canvas freezes without throwing an error. The code below describes the view hierarchy I am using to recreate this issue:

```
class Listable: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String = "Name"
    var title: String = "Title"
    var description: String = "This is a description"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var items: [Listable]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(items) { item in
                ListCell(item: item)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(self.items[0].title)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(items: testList)
    }
}

struct SecondaryListView: View {
    var items: [Listable]
    var body: some View {
        List(items) { item in
            ListCell(item: item)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(self.items[0].title)
    }
}

struct ListCell: View {
    var item: Listable
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: SecondaryListView(items: testSecondaryList)) {
            Image(systemName: "photo")
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text(item.description)
            }
        }
    }
}

let testList = [
    Listable(),
    Listable(),
    Listable()
]

let testSecondaryList = [
    Listable(),
    Listable(),
    Listable(),
    Listable(),
    Listable(),
    Listable()
]
```

**Note**: If I replace the `List` object within `SecondaryListView` with a `ForEach` (as seen below), the code compiles and runs with no issue, and I can navigate as far down the stack as I'd like.

```
struct SecondaryListView: View {
    var items: [Listable]
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            ListCell(item: item)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(self.items[0].title)
    }
}
```

Is pushing a List View from within a List View not allowed or is this a bug? It appears to cause a memory leak possibly - CPU on my main thread hits 99%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause ended up being that I was modifying the `UITableView.appearance().backgroundView` in the SceneDelegate. See below code:

SceneDelegate.swift:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"Background"), highlightedImage: nil)
```

My goal was to have a background image across all UITableViews within the app (Lists in SwiftUI still leverage UIKit components). The workaround I settled on was instead setting a background color with a UIColor init'd with a pattern image, as shown below:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"Background") ?? UIImage())
```